# Selecting from multiple tables in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to select data from multiple MySQL tables in one simple statement, my problem however is when I try to run it I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No current query in data reader

The code I am using to run the statement is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class RetrieveCars : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String Model;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
        String queryStr;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["model_id"] != null)
            {
                Model = Request.QueryString["model_id"];

                String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();

                queryStr = "";

                queryStr = "SELECT c.CarID, c.RegNumber, c.Colour , m.CarModel, m.CarMake, m.CostPerDay FROM car c INNER JOIN model m ON m.ModelID=c.ModelID WHERE c.ModelID = '" + Model + "'";

                cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();

                CarN.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CarModel"));
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're closing the reader and connection before you get the data from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are closing the reader and connection before getting any data. Just move the `.Close()` calls to the end of the function.
You also need to call `Read()` on the `reader` to actually get a row of data.

```
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Read() will return a bool indicating whether a new row has been read
// false signals no more data
while (reader.Read()) {
    // Do something with the row data
    CarN.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CarModel"));
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Still doesnt solve it but yeah it was an obvious error

Comment: I get "An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()"

Comment: Error message says to call Read(). So... call Read(). See docs for information.